# Manipulating dates to get current document with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called Document and a document is valid if the current date falls between the `start_date` and `end_date` of the document. I'm trying to define  a method that returns the current active document, but I've ran into some issues since `end_date` can be nil. What I have is

```rb
def current_valid_document
    Document.where('start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?', Date.today, Date.today).first
end
```

but the method fails for example with the following documents

Document A, start_date: 01/01/2022, end_date: 12/31/2022

Document B, start_date: 01/01/2023, end_date: nil

since today (01/03/2022) this will return Document A, but in (01/01/2023) this will return nothing as end_date of Document B is nil.

Also if I add

```rb
def current_valid_document
    Document.where('start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?', Date.today, Date.today)
    .or(Document.where(end_date: nil).first
end
```

the method will fail as this returns multiple documents instead of the current one.

How can I manipulate the dates such that I would always get the current valid document even if the end_date can be nil?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the end_date is greater than X date or is NULL. But `or` won't work for that, as it appends the OR clause without taking care of wrapping the conditions.

You can try `start_date <= ? AND (end_date >= ? OR end_date IS NULL)` instead:

```
Document.where(
  'start_date <= :date AND
  (end_date >= :date OR end_date IS NULL)',
  date: Date.new(2023, 1, 1)
)
```

Comment: This seems to work. I wonder if there is some edge cases where this would fail, but cannot come up with anything?